# How to manipulate a component on specific routes in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a simple `TopbarComponent` which basically adds a bootstrapish navbar at the top of my view.

Since 90% of my templates should have this directive included, i want to handle it through my `app.component` which looks like this:

```
import ...;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, TopbarComponent, ...],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ...]
})

@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'Dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    useAsDefault: true
}
])
```

with its template looking like this:

```
<my-topbar></my-topbar>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i want use `ngIf` (or any other way except of hiding it with css) to hide the topbar on several routes, like `/login` for example. 
I tried several approaches using `@CanAcitvate()` or implementing `OnActivate` in my `LoginComponent` (as well as trying it from my `AppComponent`) but with no effects (having problems to even get the functions to fire).
The closest i got was using the `Router` directly in my `AppComponent` like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    showTopbar:boolean;

    constructor(private _router:Router) {}

    ngOnInit():any {
        this.showTopbar = this._router.lastNavigationAttempt != '/login';
    }
}
```

and in my `app.component.html` i changed the directive to `<my-topbar *ngIf="showTopbar"></my-topbar>`

But this only works on initial load of my app, cause `ngOnInit` isn't fired on each state change. Is there a similar method i can use (and just can't find) or am i moving in the wrong direction here?

---

### Edit:

At the moment, the answer of PierreDuc doesn't work for me, but i tried a similar approach using `location.path()` like this:

```
constructor(private _location:Location) {}

private get _hideTopbar() : boolean {
    switch(this._location.path()){
        case '/register':
        case '/login':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
};
```

Too bad that i can't use the `data` property in the `@RouteConfig` in this approach. It would feel better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've crashed my head on a similar problem for a while.
The solution that i've found could be seen as tricky at first, but can resolve many similar problems of this type for me in the future.

Basically, you have to make the `router-outlet` emit an event on route change, having your `AppComponent` listening to that custom event.

The first step is to create a custom router-outlet:

```
@Directive({
selector: 'custom-router-outlet'
})
export class CustomRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private parentRouter:Router;

    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef,
            _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
            _parentRouter: Router,
            @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
    super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
    this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    }

    activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
        //***YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE***
        return super.activate(nextInstruction);
    }
}
```

This is a very basic implementation of a custom router-outlet. Your logic have to be implemented in the *activate* method, called on each route change.
In this method you can check the data property in your route.

The main problem is that, right now, *Directives* can't emit events... They accept only inputs, no outputs can be fired...

I've found a workaround to this problem: creating a *Service* for communication between Components and Directives using `EventEmitter`:

```
@Injectable()
export class PubsubService {
    private _pubSubber: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    routeisChanging(obj:any) {
        this._pubSubber.emit(obj);
    }

    onRouteChanged() {
        return this._pubSubber;
    }
}
```

The *AppComponent* subscribes to the `onRouteChanged` event:

```
subscription:any;
constructor(private _pubsubService:PubsubService) {
    this.subscription = this._pubsubService.onRouteChanged().subscribe(data => {
        /**YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE*/});
}
```

The *CustomRouterOutlet* fires the event in the `activate` method when needed:

```
activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
    //***YOUR CUSTOM LOGIC HERE***
    this._pubsubService.routeisChanging(nextInstruction.routeData.data['hideTopbar']);
    return super.activate(nextInstruction);
}
```

In this way you can easily implement a communication between the router and the `AppComponent`, with any logic.

You have to remember to inject the communication Service in the `RootComponent` of your app.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this in a few hours and will report back. Seems like a good approach.

Comment: It works perfectly. When injecting my `RoutingService` into the directive, i had weird errors when i injected it as the first param in the constructor. adding it as the last solved this for me. Thanks again, will go with this as the accepted answer, since its working good and makes sense from a structural point of view as well imho.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it is the right way, but you can add any data in the `data` parameter of the [`@RouteConfig()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteConfig-decorator.html) object. For instance you can place in the [`RouteDefinition`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouteDefinition-interface.html) of `Login` an object with a `hideTopbar` setting. You would only have to place this in a route if it should be set to true:

*warning, untested code ahead :)*

```
@RouteConfig([{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data : {hideTopbar : true}
},
//...
])
```

You can access this data in the `AppComponent` class like:

```
export class AppComponent {

    private get _hideTopbar() : boolean {
       return this._data.get('hideTopbar');
    };

    constructor(private _data:RouteData) {}

}
```

And change the `AppComponent` template to:

```
<my-topbar *ngIf="!_hideTopbar"></my-topbar>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get an error `Property 'hideTopbar' does not exist on type '{ [key: string]: any; }'.`

Comment: Any hints on this? Anyway still +1 for heading me in the right direction and raising my awareness to the data property ;)

Comment: Yes, i am sorry, i made a mistake :) I will update my answer. Had to use `RouteData` for this !

Comment: Came to `RouteData` as well, but had the problem with an error `No Provider for RouteData` but trying to inject RouteData to the providers array of the app.component gave me another error. Could it be, that this only works for components the router actually routes to? (which would explain my issues)

Comment: You should add `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` to your `bootstrap` array like: `bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]). And not in your providers array of `AppComponent`. Besides that though.. You are right, it is not possible to get `RouteData` in `AppComponent`. You should use a service to determine whether the topbar should be visible or not

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, try this

**Template**

```ts
<my-topbar *ngIf="shouldShowTopbar()">
</my-topbar>
```

**App Component**

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    hideWhen: Array<string> = ['Login', 'Help', 'SomeOtherRoute'];
       // put all the route names where you want it hidden in above array

    constructor(private _router:Router) {}

    shouldShowTopbar() {
     return (hideWhen.indexOf(this._router.currentInstruction.component.routeName) > -1);
    }

}
```

Comment: With this i get an error `EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'component' of null in [_router.currentInstruction.component.routeName != 'Login' in AppComponent@0:16]`

Comment: It will work using the `elvis operator: ?.`. But in the end, i would only use this as a workaround, because i would have to use `ngSwitch` instead for multiple cases and this doesn't seem right in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I has a similar problem. Maybe this is not the best way. But I solved it this way:

I created a new component. This component handles all the routes that need the navbar. The other routes are handled by `app.component`.

Here is some code to understand:

`app.component`

```
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/...',
    name: '...',
    component: MyComponentWhoAddsNavbar,
    useAsDefault: true
},
{   path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent
}
])


@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>', 
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

Here the `MyComponentWhoAddsNavbar`

```
@RouteConfig([
    put your routes here who need a navbar
])

@Component({
    selector: '...',
    template: `
        <navbar></navbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet> 
    `,

 })

export class MyComponentWhoAddsNavbar{}
```

Comment: Thought of this too, but not a good solution in my opinion. The topbar was only an example. I'm pretty sure i will face this kind of problem a lot for different types of components and it won't be only for showing / hiding it, but maybe to manipulate it in more comlpex ways. Couldn't do this with this approach. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in

```
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0"
```

The way that I solved this issue was to created an application-wide data object `global` and a service for it `GlobalService`. Any component can `subscribe()` to all or part of the global object. For your purposes, you should create a boolean property `isTopBar: true`. You can subscribe your `<topBar>` component to it and use that value to toggle it.

```
isTopBar: boolean;

ngOnInit(){
  this._globalService.getIsTopBar().subscribe(isTopBar => this.isTopBar = isTopBar)
}
```

`<my-topbar *ngIf="isTopBar"></my-topbar>`

A big advantage that I've found to this kind of 'GlobalService' is that I can save a lot of state information to my backend. It's less useful in you example, but imaging that you have an internal set of tab; you can save which tab the user last selected and reload to that view when they revisit the page at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the right way to do it at all, but it worked for me. It's not changing the visibility depending on the route itself, but on the Component shown in that route.

I was already using a service to feed the Navigation Bar with all the sections, and so on, so I thought it could also tell the navigation bar when to appear or not.

I basically created a subject in this service determining if it should be visible or not, with a series of methods to change this visibility.

```
@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {

  mobileNavbarIsVisible = true;
  mobileNavbarIsVisibleChanged = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  getSections() {
    return this.sections;
  }

  getMobileNavbarIsVisible() {
    return this.mobileNavbarIsVisible;
  }

  hideMobileNavbar() {
    this.mobileNavbarIsVisible = false;
    this.mobileNavbarIsVisibleChanged.next(this.mobileNavbarIsVisible);
  }

  showMobileNavbar() {
    this.mobileNavbarIsVisible = true;
    this.mobileNavbarIsVisibleChanged.next(this.mobileNavbarIsVisible);
  }
```

}

Then, I call those methods in the components that affect visibility -in my case, everytime I edit an item in a list of items, I want the navigation bar to disappear-. I call the hide method when this component is initiated, and the show method when it is destroyed.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-edit',
  templateUrl: './item-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./item-edit.component.css']
})
export class ItemEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private navigationService: NavigationService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.navigationService.hideMobileNavbar();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.navigationService.showMobileNavbar();
  }
}
```

Then, my NavbarComponent is listening to that subject, and simply appears or not depending on that value:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mobile-navbar',
  templateUrl: './mobile-navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mobile-navbar.component.css']
})
export class MobileNavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  isVisible = true;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isVisible = this.navigationService.getMobileNavbarIsVisible();
    this.navigationService.mobileNavbarIsVIsibleChanged.subscribe(
      (visibilityValue) => this.isVisible = visibilityValue
    );
  }
}
```

As I said, it's most likely not the right or the most efficient way to do it, but it works if you only want to hide the navigation bar when other component is initiated, because they simply use the Navigation Service as a way of communicating.