# Fill form after http response in angular2

Tags: http, angular, angular-promise

I'm wondering what is a best way to load a form after getting the response from server. I wrote some code where it is getting data from server and in my component I am subscribing to the response, but My UI is loading before even I get the response.

I want to use this component for both adding and editing.

**Component:**

```
@Component({
selector: 'gate',
templateUrl: '/public/app/views/gate.html',
directives: [GateFormComponent, StrategyComponent],
providers : [MyService]
})

export class MyComponent {

private id:any;

constructor(private _routeParams:RouteParams, @Inject(MyModel) private myModel,
            private myService : MyService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this._routeParams.get("id");
    if (this.id) {
        this.gateDataModel.unique_display_id = parseInt(this.id);
        this.myService.loadData(this.id)
            .subscribe(response => console.log(response));
    }
}
```

In my component, I am loading 2 components one of which has a form into which I have to load data once I get the response. And all this should only happen if I have an id available.

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService extends HTTPServices {

constructor(http:Http) {
    super(http);
}


loadData(id:number) {
    return this.query(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .catch(this.handleError)
}


private handleError(error:Response) {
    console.log("Error : ", error);
    return Observable.throw(error.text());
}
```

**HTTPServices**

```
export class HTTPServices {

private headers:Headers;
private http:Http;

defaultOptionsArgs:RequestOptionsArgs;

constructor(http:Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.headers = new Headers();
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.defaultOptionsArgs = {
        'headers': this.headers
    };
}



create(servicePath:string, model:any, options?:RequestOptionsArgs) {
    var url = this.getUrl(servicePath);
    var options = options ? options : this.defaultOptionsArgs;
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(model), options);
}

query(servicePath:string, options?:RequestOptionsArgs) {
    var options = options ? options : this.defaultOptionsArgs;
    return this.http.get(servicePath, options);
}

}
```

----Edited-----

Finally, I was able to add `@CanActivate` and it is working.

```
@Component({
selector: 'gate',
templateUrl: '/public/app/views/gate.html',
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, GateFormComponent, StrategyComponent]
})

@CanActivate(
(next: ComponentInstruction, prev: ComponentInstruction) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let id = next.params["id"];
        let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
        let http = injector.get(Http);
        if(id){
            http.get(URL)
                .subscribe((response) => {
                    console.log(response)
                    next.routeData.data["response"] = response;
                    // continue
                    resolve(true);
                }, (error) => {
                    resolve(false);
                });
        } else {
            resolve(true);
        }
    });
}

)

export class MyComponent{

private id:any;

constructor(private _routeParams:RouteParams, @Inject(MyModel) private myModel, routeData: RouteData) {
   console.log(routeData.get("response"));
}

}
```

The component is loading up and then I am getting the response

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In you component you can just use

```
template: `
 <div *ngIf="data">
  <!-- form goes here -->
 </div>
`
```

where `data` is a property that is set to some value when the response from the server arrived.

Comment: don't we have anything like ngResource in angular 2, where I can make the call and hold the UI until I get the response?

Comment: No `ngResource` currently. [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) is supposed to be able to delay routing until a returned `Promise` is resolved but I think that doesn't work properly currently. The router is being reworked anyway.

Comment: AsyncRoute? https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/AsyncRoute-class.html or maybe AsyncPipe? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/AsyncPipe-class.html

Comment: AsyncRoute loads components dynamically, AsyncPipe is to allow bindings to subscribe to `Promise` and `Observable`. I know that nobody likes to use `ngIf` for this purpose but it is dead simple and it works while `routerOnActivate` and `CanActivate` are know to have issues related to delaying route changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you leverage Angular2 routing (and it seems to be the case), you could use leverage the `OnActivate` interface and its routerOnActivate:

> Defines route lifecycle method routerOnActivate, which is called by the router at the end of a successful route navigation.
>
> For a single component's navigation, only one of either OnActivate or OnReuse will be called depending on the result of CanReuse.
>
> The routerOnActivate hook is called with two ComponentInstructions as parameters, the first representing the current route being navigated to, and the second parameter representing the previous route or null.
>
> If routerOnActivate returns a promise, the route change will wait until the promise settles to instantiate and activate child components.

You could return a promise that will be resolved when your data will be there. Here is a sample:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent {
  private id:any;

  constructor(private _routeParams:RouteParams,
              @Inject(MyModel) private myModel,
              private myService : MyService) {
  }

  routerOnActivate() {
    this.id = this._routeParams.get("id");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.id) {
        this.gateDataModel.unique_display_id = parseInt(this.id);
        this.myService.loadData(this.id)
        .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          resolve();
        });
      } else {
        resolve();
      }
    });
  }

  (...)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Thierry for the answer. I Implemented the same way as you suggested but for some reason my child components are loading even before the promise is resolved. I edited the question to have a look at what I implemented.

Comment: can you load the child with DynamicComponentLoader? https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, but since the solution can be used for your usecase too, i would recommend to have a look at the accepted answer: [How to manipulate a component on specific routes in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814390/how-to-manipulate-a-component-on-specific-routes-in-angular2)

The basic idea is to extend the `router-outlet` directive and override the `activate()` function which will be called before the next route is activated and waits for a promise to resolve.

For example you could do something like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'custom-router-outlet'
})
export class CustomRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private parentRouter:Router;

    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef,
            _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
            _parentRouter: Router,
            @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,
            private _myRoutingService:MyRoutingService) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    }

    activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
        let someRouteSpecificData = nextInstruction.routeData.data['someRouteData'];
        if(someRouteSpecificData) {
             _myRoutingService.beforeRoute(someRouteSpecificData).subscribe( () => {

                 // go on after this has been resolved
                 return super.activate(nextInstruction);

                 // or maybe cancel the route:
                 return false;

                 // or maybe do something crazy:
                 nextInstruction.componentType = MyOtherComponent;
                 return super.activate(nextInstruction);
             }

        }
        return super.activate(nextInstruction);
    }
}
```

I think you could easily change this for your purposes. You could utilize your `@RouteConfig` for example to hold some information on what should happen or be checked on a route change.

Another approach would be to use the `@CanActivate` decorator like mentioned here already, but its a bit harder to accomplish. It just feels a bit hacky at this point. I could add this later if you're interested.

Comment: I think your case best works if I have to take care of the authentication and check if the user has a session or not. But In my scenario, Its just in one instance where I want to pre-load data i.e. user wants to edit the form for which I want to load the data and then load the UI once I have the data. 


CanActivate or OnActivate would be the best option for me as of now, but for some reason `OnActivate` is not working for me and to work with `@CanActivate` I need access to `routeparams` to aceess the id for which I have to pull the data.

Comment: True, i did this because of authentication and role checks, but as well for UI trigger depending on routes. E.g. i use this to specify if a component should show a sidebar for instance. What i don't get is, why do you want this logic in your component? you say it's only one scenario but it seems it's depending on your route so it would make sense to override the default router behaviour for your needs and have this configuration (route specific permissions, ui configs etc) all in one place (`@RouteConfig`). Besides that, where's the problem accessing routeParams when you use `@CanActivate` ?

Comment: I tried using `@CanActivate`, but how do I inject `RouteParams` into it. One way I tried was by creating an `Injector` and using it to get `RouteParams` which didn't work. Any help on this would be appreciated. Referred Injector code from [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bim8OGO7oddxBaa26WzR?p=preview)

Comment: Hey Lexith, I was finally able to add `@CanActivate` decorator, but seems to be it is not working too. Refer to the edit made in the question.

Comment: Seems you got there yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to implement this using the resolve functions of the router (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#resolve-guard). This enables the http calls to be made and the route only completes when the http call observable returns.

There are good examples here: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html