# Using Observable to hide Navbar in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

My problem is the following:

I got a navbar in my `app.component` and i want to hide that for example befor someone logged in by simply setting a boolean variable to true with `ngIf`.

app.component.html:

```
<navbar *ngIf="_userLoggedIn === true" ></navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

After searching through web and reading through tons of questions here i think this should be done with Observables. But i cant figure out how to use them in a good way.
My idea was to use an Observable in a global service to share a variable so a `child component` can access and edit that variable and the `app.component` can subscribe to that variable to change `_userLoggedIn` to true (initial false) if that observable is set to true.

I using my `login.component` with the angular2 router so its displayed in the `<router-outlet>`

```
{
        path: '/login',
        name: 'Login',
        component: LoginComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
```

In that component i want to set that variable to true after successed login. 
So it changes in `app.component` and the Navbar is shown.
If you need any further code just tell me.

Would be great if someone of you can help me with my problem or got an alternative solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem and asked the question here: [How to manipulate a component on specific routes in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36814390/how-to-manipulate-a-component-on-specific-routes-in-angular2)

The main problem is (that's why i don't recommend using `@CanActivate` or `onActivate`) that you can only use these `Router` utils on Components which are routed TO, not FROM. For example if you have a topbar or sidebar in your `app.component` which has your `router-outlet` inside its template, you just can't access route Data in a good way.

That's why you can just extend the default `router-outlet` and put your logic in there.

With a `@RouteConfig` looking like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'Login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
        hideTopbar: true,
        hideSidebar: true
    }
},
```

and a template for your `app.component` looking something like this:

```
<div class="topbar" *ngIf="showTopbar">...</div>
<extended-router-outlet></extended-router-outlet>
```

you can manage this in your `app.component` class:

```
export class AppComponent {
    showTopbar:boolean;
    showSidebar:boolean;

    constructor(private _routingEventService:RoutingEventService) {
        this._routingEventService.onRouteChanged().subscribe(routeData => {
            this.showTopbar = !routeData.hideTopbar;
            this.showSidebar = !routeData.hideSidebar;
        });
    }
}
```

using an injected routingEventService like in the accepted answer i linked above:

```
@Injectable()
export class RoutingEventService {
    private _eventEmitter: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    routeIsChanging(obj:any) {
        this._eventEmitter.emit(obj);
    }

    onRouteChanged() {
        return this._eventEmitter;
    }
}
```

And then finally, build your logic in your new `router-outlet` directive like this:

```
@Directive({
    selector: 'extended-router-outlet'
})

export class ExtendedRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private parentRouter:Router;

    constructor( _elementRef: ElementRef,
                 _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
                 _parentRouter: Router,
                 @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string,
                 private _routingEventService:RoutingEventService ) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);
        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;
    }

    activate(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction): Promise<any> {
        this._routingEventService.routeIsChanging({
           name: nextInstruction.routeName,
           hideTopbar: nextInstruction.routeData.data['hideTopbar'],
           hideSidebar: nextInstruction.routeData.data['hideSidebar']
        });
        return super.activate(nextInstruction);
   }
}
```

With this approach, you can even handle other route specific logic, for example to check authentication or roles, as i explained here with the same approach in my answer to the following question:

[Fill form after http response in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36988929/fill-form-after-http-response-in-angular2/36990427?noredirect=1#comment61539993_36990427)

Hope it helps.

Comment: It took me a while to understand that because im relative new to angular2 but after that it worked pretty good for me.
Thank you @lexith for your fast and good answer.
You helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. Fyi: you should probably see this as a workaround though. the router gets more and more love from the ng team anyway and will eventually make things easier in the future. actually a colleague of mine told me just now that he found a one-liner solution for this scenario by subscribing to the router but i hadn't the time to look into it yet.

Comment: thx for that info. We will see how we should handle this when Angular2 is final. But it would be greate if you could let me know if there is a better or maybe easyer way to do this.

Comment: Could i store a user object in a way like that? So i could set a user after login and then access that user from other components.

Comment: You could, but i would not suggest it. Better would probably be a service, like an "authService". Mine uses localstorage to get / set user data and i utilize this with my "authService". Of course you can access this wherever you inject it.